# unable to copy python script dependencies in DockerFile

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile

I'm working on a project in Windows 10 where I have to create a docker image to run a python app using a DockerFile . I have to import pip , python  and the libraries time and request for my app to run . However I get an error when building the Docker image when the script dependencies time and request have to be imported . 
My error :

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement time (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for time
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 20.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

My DockerFile :

```
 FROM ubuntu:16.04
 MAINTAINER name <vskentos1@gmail.com>
 RUN apt-get update 
 RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
 RUN pip3 install time requests 
 RUN mkdir /script  //create new directory 
 COPY ex2.py /script  //add python script in new directory 
 ENTRYPOINT ["python" , "/script/ex2.py"]
```

What I have tried : 
CMD :

```
pip install --pip upgrade
```

And I get that pip has been installed to the latest version :

```
 C:\Windows\system32>pip install --upgrade pip
 Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\vasilis\anaconda3\envs\environment\lib\site- 
 packages (20.1.1)
```

However my image gets the same error when the time library is imported . 
I would appreciate your help with guiding me through this task .
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you don't need to (and can't, since it's not present on pypi) install `time` package. It's built-in: https://docs.python.org/3/py-modindex.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the module was already installed in the python version . Deleting it's installation made my program run